# C++ Segmentation error

Tags: c++

My program keeps on giving the "[project].exe has stopped working" error. After some debugging the line

`HitInfo hitInfo = (*it)->intersection(ray);`

gives me a `Signal : SIGSEGV:Segmentation fault` after which (if clicking on resume again) the program crashes.
I have read that this error can be caused by a null pointer, trying to access read-only memory and pointing to something that no longer exist. But I cannot find the exact problem in my case.

My code is the following

```
HitInfo Mesh::intersection(const Ray & ray){
    HitInfo bestHitInfo(DBL_MAX);
    for(std::vector<IFace*>::iterator it = faces.begin(); it != faces.end(); ++it) {
        HitInfo hitInfo = (*it)->intersection(ray);
        if(hitInfo.getT() < bestHitInfo.getT()){
            bestHitInfo = hitInfo;
        }
    }
    bestHitInfo.setHitMaterial(Material(mtrl));
    return bestHitInfo;
}
```

The function `intersection(ray)` does never get accessed in its respective class, it just throws the error once it tries to pass that line of code.

The `intersection(const Ray & ray)` function is being inherited multiple times but since it never gets accessed, not in the parent nor child classes, I don't think that is the problem.

Any help on why this error is thrown or on what would be the best way to find it would be great.

----EDIT----

This is the method that adds the FlatFaces to my faces vector. FlatFaces is a subclass of IFace. The logic in creating the faces is correct and maybe not useful for the question, but added all just to be sure.

```
void Mesh::readFile(const std::string & filename){
    std::ifstream inf(filename.c_str());
    if (!inf) {
        std::cout << "Mesh file " << filename << " could not be opened!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    int vertices, vectors, faces;
    inf >> vertices >> vectors >> faces;

    for(int n = 0; n < vertices; n++){
        double a,b,c;
        inf >> a >> b >> c;
        verts.push_back(Point(a, b, c));
    }
    for(int n = 0; n < vectors; n++){
        double x,y,z;
        inf >> x >> y >> z;
        norms.push_back(Vector(x, y, z));
    }
    for(int n = 0; n < faces; n++){
        int a;
        inf >> a;
        std::vector<Point> facesVerts;
        std::vector<Vector> faceNorms;
        for(int n =0; n < a; n++){
            double point;
            inf >> point;
            facesVerts.push_back(verts[point]);
        }
        for(int n = 0; n < a; n++){
            double norm;
            inf >> norm;
            faceNorms.push_back(norms[norm]);
        }
        FlatFace face = FlatFace(&verts[facesVerts[0]], &verts[facesVerts[1]], &verts[facesVerts[2]], norms[faceNorms[0]]);
        this->faces.push_back(&face);
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Just by the declaration of that iterator I'd strongly suspect that which you mentioned: a dangling pointer, and indeterminate pointer, or outright-nullptr. I'm sure there is a reason you're not using `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IFace>>` (or some other smart pointer class). But for the life of me I can't think of what that reason would be. Your debugger is your best friend right now. *Use it*.

Comment: I'm not really comfortable (yet) with c++ debugging, started c++ couple days ago and i find the low amount of variable info (compared to java) very annoying. I have no reason for using this iterator over any other, this is a piece of code supplied in the course I'm following. Which makes the idea there is an error in it even stranger... Currently stuck with debugging at 'found where, but no idea why'

Comment: The error doesn't lie in this code, but the code that is setting the faces vector. Btw your for loop could be rewritten to use std::minimum.

Comment: Not regarding the comments given, but could someone explain what is wrong with my question since it got downvoted? So I can make sure I wont make the same mistakes next time.

Comment: @Daniel, do u mean the error is wherever I added values to the faces vector?

Comment: @ThomasS "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Add this to the very beginning of your loop: if (not *it) throw std::logic_error("element " + std::to_string(std::distance(faces.begin (), it))); all in one line

Comment: It's possible that you might be adding null pointers. On the other hand, you could be adding objects they get `delete`ed before this function. Since you come from Java it could also be possible that you added pointers to stack allocated objects. I guess we need to see all code that touches the faces vector.

Comment: @Daniel, I added the piece of code u gave me but the error does not get thrown. I will try to add the code where the vector gets filled to the question.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Concerning your code: unless necessary I'd advise against the use of pointers here. And if you need a pointer, then you should think about who is owning the respective object (and thus responsible for deleting it). Then use an appropriate smart pointer. Never use raw pointers except for learning and where you know that a smart pointer won't do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FlatFace face = FlatFace(&verts ...
```

will be allocated on the stack. You add the address of a object on the stack to your vector. When you later iterate over your vector, this address is no longer valid because the object is no longer on the stack.

You could use a vector over shared pointers (`std::vector<std::shared_ptr<FlatFace>>`)

Comment: Is there a way to not have the address be no longer valid without changing the type of vector I'm using? I don't really understand how an object is or isn't on the stack. The face object should be saved and the vector should only have pointers to those face objects.

Comment: You could use the `new` keyword to create a object on the heap. But you have to delete the memory by yourself (with `delete`). Instead of `FlatFace face = FlatFace` you write `faces.push_back(new FlatFace(your arguments);`. Remember to delete the object later on. This can be done when you don't need the object anymore (`delete pointer_to_your_face`)... I would recommend you to read a tutorial about stack/heap usage in C++.

Comment: Thank you very much! I still have problems with the concept of 'new' in c++, it's so different to java. Guess I'll go search for a good tutorial.